# Annotate __init__ when creating class

Tags: python, types, mypy

I was wondering whether there is a way to provide annotations (a.k.a. type-hints) for an `__init__` function.
Concretely, I have a class that implements the `Mapping` interface and I would like to make it possible to inherit from this class to add information about expected types (similar to `dataclasses.dataclass`, `typing.TypedDict`, and/or `typing.NamedTuple`).

To give a bit of an example: the class could look something like

```py
from typing import Any, Mapping

class MyClass(Mapping[str, Any]):
    
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        return self._kwargs[key]

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        try:
            return self.__getitem__(name)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name) from None
```

and the sub-class would be implemented as follows

```py
class SubClass(MyClass):
    foo: int
    bar: str
```

This code already makes it possible for `mypy` to infer that something like

```py
o = SubClass(foo=3, bar="test", baz=None)
print(o.foo)
```

is expected to work.
However, the following (non-functional) snippet would not be flagged.
After all, it is not possible to properly annotate `__init__`.

```py
o = SubClass(bar="test", baz=None)
print(o.foo)
```

One possible solution would be to require that `__init__` is overridden in every subclass,

```py
class SubClass(MyClass):
    foo: int
    bar: str

    def __init__(foo: int, bar: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(foo=foo, bar=bar, **kwargs)
```

but I was hoping for something more elegant (i.e. with less duplication).

I did stumble upon a couple of possible workarounds, but none of them really feel like the *right* solution:

- Wait for [PEP 692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/) to be accepted.
  However, I couldn't help but notice that simply adding annotations to functions after they have been defined, does not work. E.g.

  ```py
  def test1(val: int):
      print(val)

  def test2(val):
      print(val)

  test2.__annotations__ = {"val": int}
  test1(val="")  # error: expected "int"
  test2(val="")  # okay
  ```

  Therefore, I am not sure if this would actually work for my use-case.
- Inspired by the implementation of [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1022-L1039) and [`collections.namedtuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46ccb35a400b1abe8c29ad2d7f17295610d768c7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L433-L438), a possible solution would be to use `eval` to create the `__init__` function on-the-fly, but it feels so hacky that I would hope there is a better solution.
- I also thought about setting the `__signature__`, which is used by `inspect`, but that is probably useless, since `mypy` seems to parse the code directly. I did not really try it out, though.

Therefore, I was wondering whether there is somebody out there who might know of a cleaner solution to get type-hints for an `__init__` function like this.

Comment: Your superclass is unnecessarily general. You don't want to store arbitrary attributes; you want to *access* available attributes. First, I would define `__getitem__` in terms of `getattr` and not bother overriding `__getattr__` at all. Second, you don't want such a general `__init__` method: you want a *specific* `__init__` based on the annotated names.

Comment: This is why `dataclasses` takes great care to dynamically and safely generate a class rather than using inheritance. `dataclass` works for static typing because type checkers are programmed to know about it, not because there is a clean way to combine dynamic behavior with static type checking.

Comment: There's only so much elegance available when trying to graft static type checking onto a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @chepner I get your point. However, I would argue that the behaviour I am trying to annotate is not dynamic: before running any code (at "compile time"), I know exactly what the type should be. I just want to know if there is a way to annotate it. Also, I do not quite understand why you would consider my MWE superclass **unnecessarily** general.

Comment: Because you are immediately restricting what a subclass can hold. You have a violation of the Liskov Substitution principle: `MyClass` says you can assign arbitrary attributes to an instance, but the subclasses contradict that.

Comment: That is a valid point, but is Liskov really important/relevant for constructors?

Comment: It's a grey area. Technically, no, because the LSP means a *value* of the subclass should be useable anywhere a value of the superclass is, and values of the superclass aren't intended to be passed to the subclass `__init__` method. *But*, given a list `L` with static type `List[MyClass]`, I should be allowed to write something like `for x in L: x.foobar = 3`, and it should work no matter whether `x` is a direct instance of `MyClass` or an instance of `SubClass`. That's the sense in which the LSP is violated.

Comment: If (after looking more closely at your `Subclass.__init__`), you just want to ensure that `Subclass` instances have `foo` and `bar` *in addition to* any other attributes, rather than restricting it to *only* `foo` and `bar` (like a dataclass), I would argue the DSL you've created for defining `Subclass` is, at least, misleading.

Comment: @chepner That would indeed have been the plan. Actually, this syntax would be pretty much equivalent to that of [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), so it should not be more misleading than that.

Comment: `TypedDict`, though, is something that `mypy` et al. specifically know about. It's a special case, not something you could design and use from first principles. (It's also not a subclass of a more general class. If you could do what `TypedDict` does without special support, it wouldn't have needed a PEP to add to the `typing` module.)

Comment: Is [PEP681 `dataclass_transform`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/) similar to your desired solution? If yes, then you'll have to simplify your implementation in order to use this decorator or write your own `mypy` plugin that parses this stuff correctly (most probable solution, IMO, but technically difficult for maintainers and unclear for inexperienced users). The latter is a solution if you need something different, though: if you can explain it on runtime, then you can [almost] always do the same statically too - but nobody says there is an easy way.

Comment: @SUTerliakov The `dataclass_transform` does look like it might provide the elegance that I'm looking for. However, I am not sure why the implementation would need to be simplified. I probably have a misunderstanding on how it works, since I did not manage to get a quick test (in https://mypy-play.net) to work. Could you maybe elaborate on this a bit (i.e. formulate an answer)?

Comment: First, `dataclass_transform` is not supported by `mypy`. Second, `dataclass` (and consequently `dataclass_transform`) does not have ability to pass extra kwargs, like you want. So the best thing I can suggest using PEP681 can **only** allow explicitly declared fields. Pyright supports this transformation.

Comment: [See pyright playground](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIAK6eY2MC_4WRTW_CMAyG7_kVFhda1HHZrVKnoWmniV1W7YJQFMBFETSpHKPR_folaSkd27Rc8uH3fezYFdkauG202YOuG0sMC9NmsFRNeMugbBt8VySqq1DimdE4bY27eHaK1faonJNMyrjKUi2ELKG4-JOpLKepEOLxF2mSih1WUKsDyrqVMZpsjy4HWaZw9-C3XIBfhHwiAz7kSVEGy_YpyvuCV44pC19Yp50lgKXURrOUicNjlcFsdvhQtHe9IqwQmMvu2RfdHcQIsEfWjPXAOGCbg88Vy_Pprqi-xjFx5dXrG5pipoFmVI1_4JhGlx_8UV2BkQ5KPG-xYXjB9pnI0g1CaYew8BXozYkxKjo_xDG_WoNhVN8G0vf77bTpG941vm9iZW0O2nC8bBTF3whhfTMHh9cU91mIFhNGx5Nw_ixCtlQ05N2JnXtReuP73_AFaAHHq8YCAAA%3D)